# I just received approx. a bajillion rep because I'm "trusted on other sites"?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

I thought it was a bug when I saw that ol' green box with 1600 inside. I've just received 100 rep on all the SE sites that I'm on. Is this a new thing? Is it for real or a bug? It's scared me (a little)!

Comment: No, we trust you.  Don't make us regret it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it's not a bug and it's not new. You recently reached 200 reputation, thus you received 100 extra reputation for each Stack Exchange site you have an account on. You will also now receive another 100 for every future account on a Stack Exchange site.

You can also read this related question:
[Award account association bonus automatically upon reaching 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)

Comment: So, you mean... I don't have to give them back? :)

Comment: You are correct :)

Comment: No, [you don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164224/can-stack-exchange-bonus-be-lost).